# not understanding double forwarding of an lvalue - when passed by value

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <typename Func, typename... Args>
void proxy(Func f, Args&&... args) {
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void real_func(vector<int> v) {
    cout << "size: " << v.size() << endl;
}

void multicast_func(vector<int> v) {
    proxy(real_func, std::forward<vector<int>>(v));
    proxy(real_func, std::forward<vector<int>>(v));
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> ints = {1, 2, 3};
    multicast_func(ints);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
size: 3
size: 0
```

why isn't it 3, 3? at what point does this lvalue become an rvalue and gets moved-from?

Comment: `std::forward` serves no purpose outside a templated context. You either `std::move` or you don't.

Comment: `std::forward<vector<int>>(v)` is effectively `std::move(v)`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I know - but this is taken out of a generic piece of code (a macro) and the ```vector<int>``` could be ```vector<int>&&```.

anyway I still don't understand the current behavior of the program.

Comment: @onqtam If you a vector is moved from, it becomes empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::forward` is intended to be used with universal references.

The parameter of `multicast_func` is not an universal reference, so `std::forward` makes no sense:

```
void multicast_func(vector<int> v) {
    proxy(real_func, std::forward<vector<int>>(v));
    proxy(real_func, std::forward<vector<int>>(v));
}
```

In this case, it effectively acts like `std::move` (because the template parameter is not an (lvalue) reference).

Answer (score 4):

The prototype for `std::forward` called in your code is:

```
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t ) noexcept;
```

When called with non-reference type, it effectively makes an rvalue reference out of the argument, which than is moved from. `std::vector` is guaranteed to be empty after being moved from it, so `size` becomes 0.

Answer (score 1):

> at what point does this lvalue become an rvalue and gets moved-from?

At the 1st time `proxy` is invoked `v` is converted to an rvalue, and then gets moved-from when passed to `real_func`.

```
void multicast_func(vector<int> v) {

    // the return type of std::forward is T&&, i.e. vector<int>&& here
    // for functions whose return type is rvalue reference to objec, the return value is an rvalue
    // that means v is converted to an rvalue and passed to proxy
    proxy(real_func, std::forward<vector<int>>(v));

    // v has been moved when passed to real_func as argument
    proxy(real_func, std::forward<vector<int>>(v));
}
```

The usage in `proxy` is the general usage of `std::forward`; according to the argument is an lvalue or rvalue, the template parameter will be deduced as `T&` or `T`. For `T&` `std::forward` will return an lvalue, for `T` `std::forward` will return an rvalue, so the value category is preserved. When you specify the template argument solely such capacity is lost.

Comment: @onqtam Answer revised.

Answer (score 1):

`std::forward`, when not given a reference type, will cast provided object to an rvalue.  This means the first call to

```
proxy(real_func, std::forward<vector<int>>(v));
```

will make `v` an rvalue which means it will move it into `real_func`.  The second call then uses that moved from object and you get the size of `0` since it has been emptied.

This makes sense if we look at the function.  The version of `std::forward` you are calling is

```
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t ) noexcept;
```

Since you passed `std::vector<int>` for `T` that means it will return a `std::vector<int>&&`.  So, even though `v` is an lvalue, it is converted to an rvalue.  If you want to maintain the lvalue-ness of `v` then you need to use `std::vector<int>&`.  That gives you `std::vector<int>& &&` and reference colapse rules turns that into `std::vector<int>&` leaving you with an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

In the first call of `proxy`, the parameter `vector<int> v`(in function `real_func`) is move constructed from the rvalue, so `v` (in function `multicast_func`) has been empty.
But if you change the type of paremeter as `cosnt vector<int> &`, the result will be 3, 3. Because the move constrctor has not been called.

```
void real_func(const vector<int>& v) {
    cout << "size: " << v.size() << endl;// the output is 3, 3
}
```